# How to round a number of bytes to a given section alignment in a Windows PE header?

Tags: c, windows, portable-executable

The MSDN page for [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mentions file and section alignment.

Then the description of the `SizeOfHeaders` member reads as follows:

> The combined size of the following items, rounded to a multiple of the value specified in the FileAlignment member.
>
> - e_lfanew member of IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
> - 4 byte signature
> - size of IMAGE_FILE_HEADER
> - size of optional header
> - size of all section headers

Calculating the combined size is simple enough, but how do I round the total to a multiple of the `FileAlignment` member value (512 bytes, for example)?

### EDIT

I've got the combined total of the various headers. I'm then using modulus with 512 to get the remainder. I guess this remainder needs to be padded somehow.

Comment: This is not related to MSDN, the PE file header or windows at all. What you are asking is a simple logic question: how to round a number up to an multiple of x.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm using C. I'll add that tag.

Comment: @MarkJansen That's one way of looking at it. I stumbled on this problem when I was learning about the PE header on Windows, so it's contextual information (for me, at least).

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, that link helps a lot. I was searching with terms such as `section alignment` and didn't find anything.